# How to download folders from a huge tar.gz file?

Tags: python, linux, python-requests

I have a URL which is a download link http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/lfw.tgz
It is a huge file with multiple folders tar into one tgz file.
I want to download the file in chunks and want to trigger some event when one folder gets downloaded.

I am using Python's requests library to download the file, I know how to download the file in the chunks but is there any way to download folder by folder and trigger some event when the file is downloaded?

I am okay if I have to use some Linux utility, I can execute the command using subprocess but is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You need to download the entire file before you can do anything with it. Then you can decompress it and use tar to extract what you want from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not treat tar.gz file as a folder so that you can download it folder by folder, You have to download the full file once it is on your machine you can use Python to read it in chunks.